# not able to install a python package

Tags: python-3.x, chatbot

I am trying to install a module in python but it is throwing me below error. I dont understand. I am also not able to find wheel file for this module.

Anyone else imported this module ?

Module Name :generatengrams

```
pip install generatengrams
from generatengrams import ngrammatch
```

**Getting below error:**
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement generatengrams (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for generatengrams

Answer (score 3):

```
pip install ngram
```

Check [Python ngram. PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/ngram/)

Comment: Thanks, but I want to install generatengrams package